# Looping over a vector efficiently in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

In Matlab we have this scenario:

```
v =[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 .... N N N N];
```

where the elements in v are always in INCREASING order from 1 to N and we know the value for N. We want to count number of '1's '2' ... in v.

For sure we can use a loop like the followings:

```
for i =  1 : N
    % method A
    tic
    ind = find(v == i)
     ---> do sth with ind 
    t1 = toc;

    % method B
    tic
    ind = v(v == i)
     ---> do sth with ind 
    t2 = toc;

    % method C
    tic
    ind = ismember(v , i)
     ---> do sth with ind 
    t3 = toc;


end
```

The time is takes for each of these method is roughly equal to $t1=0.02  sec$, $t2=0.02 sec$ and $t3=0.03 sec$. In my real work, N is huge and the entire loop takes sth between 2 -3 hours!

Might you have any ideas that time for doing this process could be increased? Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Specific case : Sorted input, Counts only**

If you are looking to get the counts, few approaches could be suggested here.

Approach #1 :

```
accumarray(v(:),1)
```

Approach #2 :

```
diff([0 find([diff(v) 1])])
```

Approach #3 :

```
histc(v,1:max(v))
```

For performance, I would bet on `diff`, then `accumarray` and last one on `histc`.

---

**Generic case : Unsorted input, Counts & indices**

For a generic case when input vector `v` is not sorted and you might also need the indices corresponding to each group of identical numbers, here's one approach to store the indices in a cell array -

```
[~,sort_idx] = sort(v);
sorted_v = v(sort_idx);
counts = diff([0 find([diff(sorted_v) 1])])
indices_per_grp = mat2cell(sort_idx,1,counts);
```

Sample run -

```
v =
     2     1     3     3     2     4     1     2     1     1     4     3     4   3
counts =
     4     3     4     3
indices_per_grp{1} =
     2     7     9    10
indices_per_grp{2} =
     1     5     8
indices_per_grp{3} =
     3     4    12    14
indices_per_grp{4} =
     6    11    13
```

Comment: But the OP asked for getting an increased time !  ;)

Comment: @macduf Then OP would `fliplr` my suggested order ;)

Comment: fliplr, matlab power!

Comment: Whoa.  `accumarray` screams.  I really need to learn how that thing works (i.e., force myself to use it more).

Comment: @TroyHaskin We did some benchmarks with Ray on comparing `accumarray` and `histc`. `accumarray` basically was crazy fast. `diff` I have known to be quite efficient, especially with huge arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Approach #1 and Approach #2  and both are very efficient.  If I asked this question that we need the "indices" as well and the elements could be non-increasing, would your answer change?

Comment: @YAS Yup! It would change then!

Comment: @Divakar I can't remember what post that was, but `histc` and `accumarray` was comparable to each other.  `histc` was slightly faster probably due to the minimal overhead required to simply count occurrences.  `accumarray` is a more general function.

Comment: @YAS The fact that the elements are in any order, not necessarily ordered doesn't change the way you call `accumarray` when counting up occurrences.  It will work regardless.  However, if you want the indices of where the values are occurring, something like this will work:  `out = accumarray(v(:), (1:numel(v)).', [], @(x) {sort(x)});`  This will return a cell array where each cell will give you the locations of where each value occurred.  `sort` is required because the indices that get binned to each unique ID come in random order, so sorting guarantees correct ordering in increasing format.

Comment: @YAS Added new approach for that. Basically we need to store the indices in a cell array. On that this post suggests a `mat2cell` based approach. Also, Ray has suggested an `accumarray` based approach, which must work too. Would leave it to you to see to time all these methods, good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng It was some image processing problem that led to compare histc and accumarray, right? I can't recall what problem that was. Would be good to test out again and seal it once and for all I think! I might add those in this post.. soon!

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks, I found the comments very useful. Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

I'm partial to [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html?refresh=true) here:

```
counts = sum(bsxfun(@eq,v(:),1:max(v)));
```

Comment: I was interested to use bsxfcn . It seems  however your suggestion is nto ready to be used: 

Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each
other.

Comment: @YAS Use `sum(bsxfun(@eq,v(:),1:max(v)))`. Your `v` is a column vector it seems.

Comment: Thanks. I receive this memory error:

Requested 21622187x234934 (4730.9GB) array exceeds maximum array
size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may
take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See
array size limit or preference panel for more information.

Comment: @YAS (1) The posted code assumed a row vector per the example in the question; however, you have the right solution by simply column-ing it.  (2) How big is `N` here?

Comment: I do appologize. with your original code and row vector, I recieve the same memory error. N is about 250000 ;

Comment: @YAS Ah.  That explains it.  `bsxfun` is building a 250000^2-sized matrix which `sum` collapses to a row vector.  For such a large `N`, @Divakar's answer is better since it does not do this,

Answer (score 0):

Since they are sorted, you can make this much more efficient!

how about

```
lastfound = 1;
for i =  1 : N
   % find first location after current pos, where value is i
   indStart = find(v(lastfound:end) == i, 1)
   % find first location, after this, where value is not i
   indEnd   = find(v(indStart:end) ~= i, 1)
   % now you have the range indStart:indEnd-1
   ...

   lastfound = indEnd; % start next one after the end of the current value
 end
```

i.e. just search forwards from last found item.

`find(..., 1)` finds just the first item, I believe.

Comment: This almost does what the OP already tried with `find`. In fact, I'm quite sure `find` does a linear search so even if the array is sorted, `find` will give you the same complexity for searching regardless of what state the array is in.

Comment: Well the point is that it searches only once over the whole array, rather than once for every value of `i`. In other words, it should speed up by a factor of `N`. Since find is only searching up to the point where the next   value change occurs, it ought to be much faster, right?